# How can I sync two firefox's that run on different Operating Systems?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, firefox, sync, bookmarks

I have a machine that I dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.04. I have Firefox 3.5 installed on both. I'm always switching back and forth and have one bookmark in one but not the other. How can I sync the two Firefox's?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[XMarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) add-on does this. If you want a one-time bookmark copy you can export your bookmarks on one PC and import them on another, else for an indefinite sync you will want XMarks.

---

even though you already accepted this answer, another possibility is to have Ubuntu automatically mount your Windows partition upon boot and use the same bookmark file on Windows for the Firefox you have installed on Ubuntu. To achieve this, you could simply remove the bookmarks file from Ubuntu, and replace it with a symbolic link that points to the bookmarks file on the mounted Windows 7 partition. Just a thought.

Comment: Surely you mean a symlink?

Comment: ah yes, hardlinks require that the destination exists. Forgot about that tidbit, thanks!

Comment: xmarks made my bookmarks a mess, since then I never tried it again..

Answer (score 18):

Check out the [Mozilla Weave](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868) extension. This is Mozilla's excellent cross-platform extension for syncing Firefox installations.

The current release will sync:

- Bookmarks
- Browsing history
- Saved passwords
- Open tabs
- Preferences
- Location Bar shortcuts
- [Personas](http://labs.mozilla.com/personas/)

In addition, there is ongoing development to the extension to allow it to sync auto-completion data and even extensions.

Also, check out this Wikipedia page on browser sync tools:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_browser_synchronizers

Comment: OMG wikipedia has a comparison page on everything. +1

Comment: I use weave to sync my desktop and laptop bookmarks. The current version 0.51 will sync bookmarks, forms, history, passwords, preferences and tabs and works really well. Just remember to use the same pass phrase between installs.

Comment: Nowadays is called Firefox Sync and it's a built-in feature in Firefox.:D

Answer (score 2):

FEBE does a great job as it backups all of the settings of firefox, addons included...

Answer (score 0):

In the Firefox 2.x days I used [Google Browser Sync](http://www.google.com/tools/firefox/browsersync/) for this, but that wasn't supported on Firefox 3. Since then I never used anything else, but have heard good things about [Xmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2410)

Xmarks is actually recommended on the "Google Browser Sync is dead" page

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Bookmarks option on the [Google toolbar](http://toolbar.google.com), if you have it installed on both applications. Basically you can maintain your bookmarks with Google, and access them over the web (through your account's Web History) or through the toolbar drop-down menu. This effectively synchronizes across browsers and OSes.

I realize a lot of people don't like Google's long arm and are distrustful of their multitude of services, so this may not be a good option for anyone. Personally, I don't mind if Google knows that I like Shockwave's [daily jigsaw](http://www.shockwave.com/contentPlay/shockwave.jsp?id=jigsawpuzzles&dwin=1&memberStatus=NotSignedIn), for example.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the whole Google spying on me thing. It's just that their toolbar sucks (as far a UI goes).

Comment: I find their toolbar very useful, and very configurable. I like it a certain way, so every time I install it on a new browser I drop what I don't need and add what I do, and never worry about it again.