# Any browser sync solution which supports sync profiles like XMarks?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firefox, sync, bookmarks

XMarks is going down. [I see that](https://superuser.com/questions/16530/how-to-sync-bookmarks-between-firefox-chrome-and-safari-on-multiple-computers) [there are](https://superuser.com/questions/20437/how-can-i-sync-two-firefoxs-that-run-on-different-operating-systems) [alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/2528/best-way-to-sync-firefox-add-ons-and-bookmarks-between-machines), but according to [the Wikipedia comparison page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_browser_synchronizers), so far none of these seems to support **sync profiles**, which allow me to sync only certain bookmarks to certain machines. To me this was one of the highlights of XMarks.

**Anyone know a solution which supports sync profiles?**

Our family uses Firefox, on Windows and Ubuntu. The most important point for us is syncing bookmarks, although addon sync would not hurt either.

Comment: How do you mean by "profiles" ? If it's just across Firefox then Firefox sync is the way to go.

Comment: @Sathya, my first link above points to that same question you refer to. And no, this is not a duplicate of that one, because I am asking specifically for a solution capable of handling sync profiles. In brief, it means that all my bookmarks are synced, but I can have bookmarks which are replicated only on my home machine, while others only on my work machine.

Comment: you're right, I've removed my comment, my close vote still remains, though it should age off in couple of days

Comment: I'd very much like an answer to this as well, even though XMarks is probably not dead.  Alternatives are good.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there may be life in Xmarks after all - here's hoping: [Xmarks blog](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1945)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox on all the machines, it looks like that functionality is now built in.  It's called Firefox Sync.

```
Firefox Sync lets you take all your Firefox data (such as your bookmarks,
history, passwords, add-ons and open tabs) with you wherever you go. 
You just set up Firefox Sync on your home computer and your Firefox data 
will be securely stored on our servers and synchronized automatically from then 
on. Then, when you set up Firefox Sync on your work computer (or even your 
phone running Firefox), your Firefox data will be automatically synchronized 
with your home computer.
```

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you

**Update:** I do see that you're looking to sync specific bookmarks, not the whole lot of them.  Firefox Sync doesn't appear to have that feature yet, but it still may be a viable option.

**Update 2:** If you were, say, in a work desktop, work laptop, home computer environment, and only wanted to sync the work links, you could sync all the bookmarks on the work machines.  Then, if you needed a work bookmark at home, log into the web interface for it.  It's not perfect, but it's something.

Answer (score -1):

If you're that desperate to save XMarks, perhaps participate in the pledge, [build your own xmarks server](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/09/29/move-your-xmarks-to-your-own-server/), stuff like that.

Comment: I wouldn't say I am desperate to save XMarks - I am primarily interested in a _solution_, not in a brand :-)